# EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, SETTINGS) display wrong tablespace parameters

Tags: postgresql, explain, postgresql-12, tablespace

PostgreSQL 12.8

I have a tablespace called `mattermost` and a database `mattermost-dev` in it.

```
postgres=# \l+ mattermost-dev
                                                 List of databases
      Name      |   Owner    | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    | Access privileges | Size  | Tablespace | Description
----------------+------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------+-------+------------+-------------
 mattermost-dev | mattermost | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |                   | 28 MB | mattermost |
```

I have set parameters for this tablespace:

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM pg_tablespace where spcname = 'mattermost';
   oid    |  spcname   | spcowner | spcacl |                     spcoptions
----------+------------+----------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------
 39843057 | mattermost |       10 |        | {random_page_cost=1.1,effective_io_concurrency=200}
```

But when I execute any query in database `mattermost-dev`, `EXPLAIN` shows me `effective_io_concurrency = 2` - that is the value for the default tablespace. And it does not show the `random_page_cost` parameter, because for the default tablespace it is set to the default value 4.

```
mattermost-dev=# explain (ANALYZE,  SETTINGS) select * from teammembers where userid = '3ya1arysntboz8w3in5qbny11y';
                                                                             QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on teammembers  (cost=1.39..3.53 rows=2 width=66) (actual time=0.088..0.089 rows=2 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: ((userid)::text = '3ya1arysntboz8w3in5qbny11y'::text)
   Heap Blocks: exact=1
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_teammembers_user_id  (cost=0.00..1.39 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=0.057..0.058 rows=2 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((userid)::text = '3ya1arysntboz8w3in5qbny11y'::text)
 Settings: effective_cache_size = '32256MB', effective_io_concurrency = '2', max_parallel_workers = '6', max_parallel_workers_per_gather = '3', work_mem = '2752kB'
 Planning Time: 6.430 ms
 Execution Time: 0.178 ms
```

Why does `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` in the database in a non-default tablespace display the parameters for the default tablespace?
I did not restart the instance after I set the parameters for mattermost tablespace, but only execute `pg_reload_conf();`

Do I need to restart the instance?

Comment: What do you get if you execute `select tablespace from pg_tables where tablename = 'teammembers'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXPLAIN (SETTINGS)` only shows database parameters (whatever you can see in `pg_settings` or with `SHOW`), but it does not show storage parameters of tables or tablespace options.

I concur that that would be nice information, but it is questionable how that information should be displayed: A query can affect several tables, and each could be in a different tablespace. So you would have to come up with an output format that can deal with that.

I tend to agree that an exception might be made with the default tablespace of the database you are connected to: it is highly likely that most of the tables will use the settings for that tablespace. If you want to suggest such a change in `EXPLAIN` output, you should contact the pgsql-hackers mailing list. You can promote your cause by writing a patch.